# How do I remove multiple Smart Card entries in the "run as different user" dialog?

Tags: windows-8.1, drivers, dell-latitude, runas, smartcard

I was setting up a new Windows 8.1 install on a Dell laptop our org owns. As we like to put our own software on the machines, we will wipe and reinstall from scratch. After the initial install, as I was installing drivers I somehow managed to create three "Connect a smart card" entries in the "Run as different user" dialog box. Is there any way to remove these entries?

Image for the curious:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are the same here, we like to build our own images. We just got new E7450 Latitudes and first time we were prompted for network credentials we got the image that you showed. 3 smart card options, that is ugly and to top it off we don't use smart cards. I just Disabled and stopped the service, so far no issues.

1. Open services.msc
2. Find the service 'Smart Card'
3. Double click the service to open it
4. Set the 'Startup type' to 'Disabled'
5. Stop the service.

I did it while a password prompt was open and immediately went to just username password, the smart card entries disappeared. Hope this helps!